# How to run a python program with wscript?

Tags: python, windows, autostart, wscript.shell

I am trying to run a python program with an anaconda environment (or just a python with some version) through wscript, which will be placed in a batch file, so I can run the program by just double clicking the batch file.

here is the code

```
Set WinScriptHost = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScript.Run "C:\anaconda3\envs\card_player\python.exe C:\projects\card_player\auto_play.py"
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

I have no idea why it is not working, meanwhile, run the python is perfectly working by

```
python c:\projects\card_player\auto_play.py
```

in the console.

What did I wrong?
A console pops up and disappears right away after I click the batch file...

Answer (score 0):

Replace WinScript.Run "C:\anaconda3\envs\card_player\python.exe C:\projects\card_player\auto_play.py" by the following line:

```
WinScriptHost.Run("C:\anaconda3\envs\card_player\python.exe C:\projects\card_player\auto_play.py")
```

Comment: Your script is exactly same as mine. Perhaps you tried to change something in the line?

Comment: In your question you wrote WinScript instead of WinScriptHost.

Comment: Still not working from your solution @NorbertWillhelm